# Ext JS Checkbox in Roweditor

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, checkbox

does anybody know how to set the checkbox in a RowEditor into the center position?
I use the theme "triton" with Ext JS 6.0.0.

The checkbox is placed to the top of the row, but the other fields like textfield or combobox are placed to center.

It looks like:

[image]

i already set the style object of the checkbox to `align: center` but it didn't work.

```
plugins: { ptype: 'rowediting', clicksToEdit: 2, saveBtnText: 'Übernehmen', cancelBtnText: 'Abbrechen' },

initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;
    me.store = 'MeasurementPoint';
    me.columns = [
        {
            xtype: 'actioncolumn',
            width: 50,
            sortable: false,
            hideable: false,
            resizable: false,
            menuDisabled: true,
            draggable: false,
            items: [
                {
                    icon: 'Content/images/icon_32/garbage.png',
                    tooltip: 'Löscht den Eintrag',
                    handler: function(view, rowIdx, colIdx, item, ev, record) {
                        Ext.Msg.show({
                            title: 'Löschen bestätigen!',
                            msg: 'Soll der Messpunkt \"' + record.data.Name + '\" wirklich gelöscht werden?',
                            width: 300,
                            buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
                            fn: function(btn) { if (btn === 'yes') view.ownerCt.getStore().remove(record); },
                            //animateTarget: rowIdx,
                            icon: Ext.window.MessageBox.QUESTION
                        });

                    }
                },
                {
                    icon: 'Content/images/icon_32/pencil.png',
                    tooltip: 'Bearbeitet den Eintrag',
                    handler: function(view, rowIdx, colIdx, item, ev, record) {
                        if (this.__form)
                            return;

                        this.__form = Ext.widget('window', {
                            layout: 'fit',
                            width: 500,
                            title: 'Messpunkt bearbeiten',
                            items: { xtype: 'measurementpointform', header: false },
                        }).show();
                        this.__form.down('button[itemId=save-measurementpoint]').action = 'update-measurementpoint';
                        this.__form.down('form').loadRecord(record);
                        this.__form.on('close', function() { this.__form = false }, this, { single: true });
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            dataIndex: 'Active',
            text: 'Aktiv',
            width: 70,
            renderer: AWA.ImageRenderer.CROSS,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'checkbox',
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            dataIndex: 'Manually',
            text: 'Manuell',
            width: 90,
            renderer: AWA.ImageRenderer.TICK,
            editor: {xtype: 'checkbox'}
        }
```

Thank you guys for helpful anwers

Comment: please post your code in the question too

Comment: Did you try `vertical-align: middle` ?

Comment: Dont know how to set this: Am i right with `style: {'vertical-align: 'middle'}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have overwritten the CSS and it works for me

```
.x-grid-editor .x-form-cb-wrap {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Thanks